# Assign splited string to array in elixir

Tags: string, list, elixir

I am new in elixir development. I have problem with parsing of string in elixir. Assume that I have string "Hello World from the hell". I know that I can split this like this `String.split("Hello World from the hell")`. I would like to know is the anyway to assign element of this string to list in elixir?

Comment: I don't really understand. What's the result that you want to get?

Comment: like let's say [ a ,b ,c ,d, e ] = ["Hello", "World", "from", "the", "hell"]. Simple like to create array elements in OOP, which can resize base of the size of string which I entered

Comment: you mean like `a = String.split("some string")` where a will always be the result of your string split?

Comment: Yes. a[i] = String.split("some string"). which I will have access to element of array a[i]. I know this way is not correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String.split/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/1) returns a [list](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html) - one of Elixir's fundamental data structures, along with [maps](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html) and [tuples](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html). A list is your go-to basic collection in Elixir. Even though internally it's a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), you can perform all sorts of operations on it using functions from the [Enum module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html):

```
$ iex
iex(1)> ls = String.split("Hello World from the hell")
["Hello", "World", "from", "the", "hell"]
iex(2)> i ls
Term
  ["Hello", "World", "from", "the", "hell"]
Data type
  List
Reference modules
  List
iex(3)> Enum.take(ls, 2)
["Hello", "World"]
iex(4)> Enum.at(ls, 4)
"hell"
iex(5)> [l0, l1, l2, l3, l4] = ls
["Hello", "World", "from", "the", "hell"]
iex(6)> l4
"hell"
iex(7)> Enum.take(ls, 4) ++ ["iex", "shell"]
["Hello", "World", "from", "the", "iex", "shell"]
```

As you can see [`Enum.at/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#at/3) gives you something similar to the `a[i]` style array access.

If you're worried about the efficiency of finding an element in your list - for example your input string is going to be something much longer than `"Hello World from the hell"` and you'll be getting elements from it by index many times, essentially traversing it each time, you can build a [map](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html) from it instead, and look the words by indices efficiently:

```
iex(8)> with_indices = Enum.with_index(ls)
[{"Hello", 0}, {"World", 1}, {"from", 2}, {"the", 3}, {"hell", 4}]
iex(9)> indices_and_words = Enum.map(with_indices, fn({a, b}) -> {b, a} end)
[{0, "Hello"}, {1, "World"}, {2, "from"}, {3, "the"}, {4, "hell"}]
iex(10)> map = Map.new(indices_and_words)
%{0 => "Hello", 1 => "World", 2 => "from", 3 => "the", 4 => "hell"}
iex(11)> map[0]
"Hello"
iex(12)> map[4]
"hell"
```